# System.Data.DataViewRow showing instead of value

Tags: c#

Whenever I try to run my program, after selecting `dropdownList1` data, the `dropdownlist2` populates with `System.Data.DataViewRow` text rather than populating the values.
I've tried 6 Hrs searching this but didn't find answer.

[image]

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string perfectid = string.Empty;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select [Id] from [Table] where movie_name='"+s1+"'",con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda1.Fill(dt);
    GridView g1 = new GridView();
    g1.DataSource = dt;
    g1.DataBind();
    foreach (GridViewRow dr in g1.Rows)
    {
        perfectid = dr.Cells[0].Text;

    }

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select song_name from songs where id='" + perfectid + "'", con);
    DataTable dta = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dta);

    DropDownList2.DataSource = dta;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please edit it properly...

Comment: 1 - don't concatenate sql queries (i.e. prevent sql injection, refer [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com)), use sqlparameters and use stored procedures. 2 - Why are you doing this as 2 step process, you can directly  use subquery/join in sql and get the songs list based on the movie name selected, the whole gridview+forloop is unnecessary. 3 - Did you debug and see if the sql is being formed correctly? Is the data being fetched correctly or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment:

1] Don't use string concatenation for sql query, use parameterized queries. Check the below code for use of `sqlcommand` with use of `parameters`.

2] I've clubbed both the queries using subquery so you only need to connect to database once. [This will work only if there is 1 row returned from the subquery which it should in this case as you are using ID as reference, else use `IN` operator]

3] Mapping `DropDownList2.DataSource = dta;` is not sufficient, you need to map `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` too to inform exactly which column will be mapped, I've used column ref by index but you can give name too. According to me that's the reason that it's showing `System.Data.DataViewRow` in dropdown instead of the values.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string perfectid = string.Empty;
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select song_name from songs where id=(select [Id] from [Table] where movie_name=@moviename",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moviewname", s1);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dta = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dta);
    con.Close();

    DropDownList2.DataSource = dta;
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = dta.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = dta.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!...as mentioned, "parameterized query" solved my doubt.

Comment: @moonshine Welcome. If this answer has resolved your problem, you can accept it so that the question can be termed as closed.